# How to make Jquery datatable work on 'n' number of columns?

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I am making Django web app. I used this [datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/semanticui) in it. My page has four datatable in it. All of them working but on definite number of columns say 6. When I insert 7th column, searching and pagination gets dissapear from that table.
I am confused that whether this issue is datatable specific or there is wrong with something else.

In this code given below, pagination and searching gets dissapeared but when I remove last column and last column data, it appears.

```
  <table id="confirmedDeliveries" class="ui celled table responsive nowrap unstackable" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Requested By</th> 
                            <th>Contact</th>                            
                            <th>Date Requested</th>
                            <th>From</th>
                            <th>To</th>    
                            <th>Required Delivery Date</th> 
                            <th align="center" colspan="2">Action</th>    
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody  class="new_requests">
                        {% for delivery in confirmed %} 
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{delivery.request.user}}</td>  
                            <td>{{delivery.request.contact}}</td>                             
                            <td>{{delivery.request.date_requested}}</td>
                            <td>{{delivery.request.from_address}}</td>
                            <td>{{delivery.request.to_address}}</td>
                            <td>{{delivery.request.required_delivery_date}}</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="cancel_request" data-id="{{delivery.id}}">Cancel</button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="done_request" data-id="{{delivery.id}}">Delivered</button></td>

                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Any insights would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing your `colspan="2"` - so, just use this instead: `<th align="center">Action</th>`.

If you want to use colspans and rowspans, see [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html).